# Text doesn't wrap in evenly distributed, even width flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/gxhb2xnu/1

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 4px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">foõ foõ foõ foõ foõ foõ</div>
  <div class="column">foõ</div>
  <div class="column">foõ</div>
  <div class="column">foõ</div>
  <div class="column">foõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõ</div>
</div>
```

As you can see the last column adjusts its width to accomodate the text. I'd like every column to have an equal width and to just break mid-word onto the next line.

I tried `flex-basis: 0` and `word-wrap: break-word;`, but it doesn't seem to affect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There were few mistakes that I have corrected.

1. Fixed the **flex properties** in the `column divs`.
2. Use `word-break:break- word`

> Below is the working code.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.column {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 4px;
  height: 100%;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">foõ foõ foõ foõ foõ foõ</div>
  <div class="column">foõ</div>
  <div class="column">foõ</div>
  <div class="column">foõ</div>
  <div class="column">foõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõfoõ</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `word-break: break-word;` to column class